# Codepen issue on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image]

In the above image if look at the HTML `#one` and `#two` are below one another, which is also the fact in the preview.

[image]

When I shift `#two` next to `#one` in the HTML, the preview changes...

Is it a bug? This happens in Chrome.

Link to codepen :
[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/e6z6a6z/pen/lKxdq)

Comment: If you don't want to write all your div in on line, you can do this (break line before then `>` of the closing div) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LIpgH

Comment: @ezaz Just FYI, whitespace won't be an issue if you use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`, but the container will need `overflow:hidden;` or a clearfix. (Or you can keep inline-block but alter `word-spacing` and `letter-spacing` values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug - the "whitespace" between your 2 `div`'s is processed and shown in the output too.

Comment: No, it will happen everywhere. It's simple: you typed whitespaces/line breaks in your code, you get whitespaces/line breaks in your output.

Comment: No it happens on every website

Comment: If this solves your question, you can mark it as the correct answer.